# Evaluating $\int_{\gamma}z^2e^{z^3}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, line-integrals

Note: we're not yet allowed to say derivative of holomorphic are holomorphic or even that they are continuous. hell.

---

For $\int_{\gamma}z^2e^{z^3}dz$, where $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$, $\gamma(t)=(t-1)^2+it^3$

For independence of path theorem below, choose

$$(D,a,b,f(z),F(z)) =(\mathbb C,\gamma(0)=1,\gamma(1)=i,z^2e^{z^3},\frac{e^{z^3}}{3})$$

- Let $a,b \in \mathbb C$. Let $f: D \to \mathbb C$ be continuous for open and connected $D \subseteq \mathbb C$. Let $\gamma$ be any piecewise smooth path starting at $a$ and ending at $b$. Suppose $f$ has a primitive/an antiderivative $F$ in $D$. Then $\int_\gamma f = F(b)-F(a)$.

We can do this because

1. $\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth since $\gamma$ is a smooth path since both its real and imaginary parts are smooth since both parts are polynomials.
2. $f(z)=z^2e^{z^3}$ is continuous in $D=\mathbb C$ because $f$ is entire because $f$ is the product of 2 entire functions where $e^{z^3}$ is entire because it is the composition of 2 entire functions $e^z$ and $z^3$.

Therefore, (see wolfram [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7Bi%5E3%7D%7D%7B3%7D%20-%20%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B1%5E3%7D%7D%7B3%7D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%281%29-isin%281%29%20-%20e%5E%28-i%29%2F1%3D0))

$$\int_{\gamma}z^2e^{z^3}dz$$

$$ = \int_\gamma f = \int_\gamma f(z) dz = F(b)-F(a)$$

$$= \frac{e^{i^3}}{3} - \frac{e^{1^3}}{3}$$

$$=\frac{-e}{3} + \frac{e^{-i}}{3}$$

$$= \frac{[-e+\cos(1)]+i[-\sin(1)]}{3}$$